# Python Requests behind proxy

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests, urllib2

I'm behind a corporate proxy (Isa Server).

When using urllib2 I can connect through the proxy to the internet without any problem, but when using the requests library I can't.

Here is my urllib2 code:

```
proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler({})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

page = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com')
print page.getcode()
```

This prints '200' and works fine

However when doing the same with requests I get a 407 code and doesn't work.

```
proxy_dict = {
    'http': 'http://10.20.23.5:8080',
    'https': 'ftp://10.20.23.5:8080',
    'ftp': 'https://10.20.23.5:8080'
}

page = requests.get('http://www.google.com', proxies=proxy_dict)
print page.status_code
print page.reason
```

This prints '407' and the reason: 'Proxy Authentication Required ( Forefront TMG requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied.  )'

Even if I pass to requests the proxies from urllib2 doesn't work either:

```
page = requests.get('http://http://www.google.com', proxies=urllib2.getproxies())
```

Urllib2 is doing something that requests is not.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

If your proxy requires authentication, you need to set up those variables:

```
proxy_dict = {
    'http': 'http://username:password@10.20.23.5:8080',
    'https': 'https://username:password@10.20.23.5:8080',
    'ftp': 'ftp://username:password@10.20.23.5:8080'
}
```

Comment: Why urllib2 works without the username and password?

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16703936/proxy-connection-with-python) out. May be it helps.