# How to connect to a proxy using python

Tags: python-2.7, proxy

**is it possible to create a python code so that when runned it will connect the computer to a specific proxy (knowing the proxy IP and the port)...**

just like the manual connection method in windows , you put the proxy ip and the port and it will connect you , i need a code that will do everything so that you don't need to go to setting > network> proxy>...

P.s : using python 2.7

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proxy connection with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16703936/proxy-connection-with-python)

Comment: @AleksAndreev I don't think so because the OP is talking about a proxy change in the PC, not how to make Python access Internet through a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a Python script using [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html) module to execute [netsh winhttp](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc731131(WS.10).aspx) commands.